# How do you calculate the efficiency of a steam turbine?

Tags: carnot-cycle

Yesterday I saw a comment on an article that claimed a turbine with a steam temperature of 500° F and a room temperature 70 ° F couldn't possibly have an efficiency higher than 45%. He used the carnot efficiency equation as far as I could tell, but wouldn't a turbine use an equation completely different than the carnot cycle equation?

Comment: What do you know about the Carnot engine?

Comment: One of the steam turbine cycles is called Rankine cycle and it will predict a much lower efficiency, but the thermodynamic limit is, of course, given by Carnot. Using Carnot is the poor man's argument, really. I certainly rather use Carnot in ten seconds than try to understand how to use Rankine, again... :-)

Comment: Did you read this, it's pretty comprehensive  on efficiency https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_turbine  apologies if you already did.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is about a HEAT ENGINE and the 'efficiency' is measured by heat energy input and mechanical energy output.   One can drive a turbine with any moving fluid, for example a river in a hydroelectric turbine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but wouldn't a turbine use an equation completely different than the carnot cycle equation

Yes, it would be different. And *lower.*

The Carnot cycle has the maximum possible efficiency. Bigger than *any other* thermodynamic cycle. Calculate the Carnot efficiency $\eta_C$ for any engine, and the real efficiency $\eta$ is lower (maybe much, much lower):

$$\eta_C>\eta$$

So nothing is wrong in his argument, it is just a very rough value. He just found $\eta_C$ and states that this is the maximum limit and that the real value must be lower than this - without knowing if the real value is close or much smaller. This is just a rough back-of-the-envelope value that you can always quickly find for any engine.